# IP Aliasing with QWebView (Qt / C++)

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit, qwebview, qtnetwork

Let’s see if you can shed some light on my problem. [**C++** with **Qt 5.2**, using **Qt Creator**]

Situation: I’ve got a PC with several local IP addresses assigned to the same interface (IP Aliases). The router has different configurations regarding bandwidth, NAT, connections, etc., for each local IP. I’m integrating this Local IP-switching to some Qt apps, in particular to an app that offers a nice browsing experience using **QWebView**.

What I need I : To be able to **change which local IP QWebView uses** to get its requests out.

The only thing I've managed to do -*just a patch*- is to use **STUNNEL** to map localhost ports to remote hosts through different local IPs, and using QNetworkProxy to make QWebView use those localhost ports as proxies. Thing is, for some reason proxying like this apparently spawns some problems: The user can't see several YouTuve videos, only seeing static background and "*An error has occurred*". This doesn't happen when using **NetworkProxyFactory::setUseSystemConfiguration(true)**, as every video can be seen perfectly.

**The question would be:** How can I manage IP aliases with Qt? If that's not possible, do you have any idea why proxying through STUNNEL is failing? Maybe other transparent tunneling software to try out?

In input is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: IIRC plugins (e.g. video playback, flash, etc.) may ignore routing/proxy settings. Thats why flash and Co. can nullify anonymizing techniques. They may try to use the global device route instead of your application wide setting.

Comment: That's actually very helpful regarding one of my issues, thank you!

Comment: @lgvidal Check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023680/using-qt-c-qwebview-causes-the-gui-to-run-slowly, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20800850/how-to-access-a-nested-qml-object-from-c, http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/34849, http://serverfault.com/questions/542530/ip-alias-and-port-bridging

Comment: @KhaledAKhunaifer I don't really see how any of those question has anything to do with this one. Maybe the last one a little, but doesn't really help. Are you human?

Answer (score 2):

QWebView using QNetworkAccessManager to deal with requests/responses. Only useful thing you can override is a virtual

```
QNetworkReply * QNetworkAccessManager::createRequest(Operation op, 
const QNetworkRequest & req, QIODevice * outgoingData = 0) [virtual protected]
```

which unfortunately is not really useful for your purposes..

As well I don't think the Bearer thing will work either.

So, depending on how bad you need this functionality I would look into making changes in QNetworkAccessManager to be able to pass list of allowed interfaces/ip addresses, so QTcpSocket it will bind itself to specified IP address.. and then set this AccessManager to WebView.

As far as I know specifying bind address is not supported for QNetworkAccessManager